# Is there any way to get the list of joined teams details of members?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, postman, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Is there any way to get the list of joined teams details of members except graph API? Using graph API of below link we can get the list of joined teams details of any members. Similarly, is there any other way to get the list of joined MS teams group details? I want to use these details in Microsoft bot framework.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Due to some security concern I can not use graph API as of now.

I am also exploring below link but I am not getting anything here... Looking for any REST API like graph API where I can provide the users name and I can get details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet

Comment: I don't understand what's the "security concern" that you're talking here with Microsoft Graph that too when you're planning to use Microsoft BOT framework.

Comment: Actually, application permissions which is required for fetching the details those are not in scope of my organization.

Comment: Gotcha. So it's not a security concern, rather it's part of your requirement. If i am in your place, i would set Graph API as prerequisite for my app to work, explain the benefits that you're going to get with Graph/application permissions. Apart from Microsoft Graph API whatelse to suggest; may be you can try with Powershell, CLI & i don't remember any other REST APIs exposed - even if they exists, i am not sure it will suffice your requirement.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'll try and will update here if anything I found.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a security concern, rather it's part of the requirement. If i am in your place, i would set Graph API as prerequisite for my app to work, explain the benefits that you're going to get with Graph/application permissions. Apart from Microsoft Graph API you can try with Powershell, CLI.